# Been looking for a Word sort of like Chauvinism

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that expresses a person highly prejudiced in favor of their homeland or culture. Chauvinist is too harsh and it seemed to myself and a friend that the word was just out of reach. Zealot is also too strong. Any suggestions?

Sentence: I had no idea that he was so ______. Or I had no idea was such a _______.

Comment: *Jingoist* or one of its [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/jingoist).

Comment: I believe there are words in the duplicate that meet your needs.

Comment: *Patriotic/patriot*? Or *nationalist*?

Comment: Perhaps *nativistic*?

Comment: @medica I don't think this is a duplicate. The other post asks for words *against* others; this asks for words *for* their own. They are two sides of the same coin but answers on the other post deal (properly) with just one side.

Answer (score 1):

**Flag-waver**

> an enthusiastic, demonstrative patriot

Source: [*The Oxford Dictionary of American Political Slang*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zGfiBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22enthusiastic,+demonstrative+patriot%22&source=bl&ots=kdt9mJUjZb&sig=MgRw4rAuf9lWWbc0BmjWSNsPh-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR_OODlqXMAhVL2GMKHcQQDSgQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22enthusiastic%2C%20demonstrative%20patriot%22&f=false)

Comment: I think this is a good answer—as edited, with the source of the quoted language properly cited—and I have upvoted it. I strongly recommend including a linked (if possible) citation to the source of any language you quote in an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly ethnocentric? The idea is the same, I'm just not sure if there is a noun form to describe a person who is ethnocentric.

> having or based on the idea that your own group or culture is better or more important that others